# How to use EventSubscriber in TYPO3 e.g. for symfony/workflow events?

Tags: symfony, typo3, symfony5, typo3-10.x

How is it possible to use `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface` to implement a subscriber-class, listening for events dispatched by TYPO3s PSR-14 EventDispatcher?

Let's see an example by using `symfony/workflow` for a TYPO3 extension, which works great until it comes to events. Because of [`typo3/symfony-psr-event-dispatcher-adapter`](https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/symfony-psr-event-dispatcher-adapter), the TYPO3 default EventDispatcher can be smoothly added to the `Workflow` class. So far so good.

Now I've several problems:

#### Problem 1: The event-names such as 'workflow.myname.leave'

The events dispatched by `Workflow` using a string name, instead of a FQCN like all other events dispatched in the TYPO3 life-cycle. This makes it impossible to use the common way of EventListeners registered inside the `services.yaml`, because the configuration requires a FQCN of the event-class.

```
  # this will not work because the "event" needs to be a FQCN
  Vendor\MyExt\EventListener\MyWorkflowEventListener:
    tags:
      - name: event.listener
        identifier: 'vendor-myext/MyWorkflowEventListener'
        event: 'workflow.myname.leave'
        method: 'onLeave'
```

#### Problem 2: Trying to use an EventSubscriber

The [doc recomments an EventSubscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow.html#using-events). IMO using an EventSubscriber (`Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface`) would also solve problem #1, because the configuration of events is defined as key-value array inside `getSubscribedEvents()`. (BTW this seems to be also much easier for lots of events like in this case of workflow-events, because one class can be responsible handling multiple "similar" events and will not mess-up the `services.yaml`).

Also the Symfony doc says, that implementing this interface while `autowire` and `autoconfigure` is set to `true` will be enough; the EventSubscriber should be available and listening. Maybe this is true in a plain Symfony environment, but it seems not in a context of TYPO3. Unfortunately I can't figure out why (the subscriber classes doesn't show up inside EventDispatcher->ListenerProvider->listeners array).

How to continue here?

Answer (score 0):

The TYPO3 core EventDispatcher is not able to handle or register Subscribers (yet). So for now I ended up using the `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher` in parallel to the TYPO3 default one. The Symfony EventDispatcher handles only the workflow-events in this case. It feels not as clean as I'd like to, but it works.